# Writing with lxml emitting no whitespace even when pretty_print=True

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm using the `lxml` library to read an xml template, insert/change some elements, and save the resulting xml. One of the elements which I'm creating on the fly using the `etree.Element` and `etree.SubElement` methods:

```
tree = etree.parse(r'xml_archive\templates\metadata_template_pts.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

stream = []
for element in root.iter():
    if isinstance(element.tag, basestring):
        stream.append(element.tag)

        # Find "keywords" element and insert a new "theme" element
        if element.tag == 'keywords' and 'theme' not in stream:
            theme = etree.Element('theme')
            themekt = etree.SubElement(theme, 'themekt').text = 'None'
            for tk in themekeys:
                themekey = etree.SubElement(theme, 'themekey').text = tk
            element.insert(0, theme)
```

prints to the screen nicely `print etree.tostring(theme, pretty_print=True)`:

```
<theme>
  <themekt>None</themekt>
  <themekey>Hydrogeology</themekey>
  <themekey>Stratigraphy</themekey>
  <themekey>Floridan aquifer system</themekey>
  <themekey>Geology</themekey>
  <themekey>Regional Groundwater Availability Study</themekey>
  <themekey>USGS</themekey>
  <themekey>United States Geological Survey</themekey>
  <themekey>thickness</themekey>
  <themekey>altitude</themekey>
  <themekey>extent</themekey>
  <themekey>regions</themekey>
  <themekey>upper confining unit</themekey>
  <themekey>FAS</themekey>
  <themekey>base</themekey>
  <themekey>geologic units</themekey>
  <themekey>geology</themekey>
  <themekey>extent</themekey>
  <themekey>inlandWaters</themekey>
</theme>
```

However, when using `etree.ElementTree(root).write(out_xml_file, method='xml', pretty_print=True)` to write out the xml, this element gets flattened in the output file:

```
<theme><themekt>None</themekt><themekey>Hydrogeology</themekey><themekey>Stratigraphy</themekey><themekey>Floridan aquifer system</themekey><themekey>Geology</themekey><themekey>Regional Groundwater Availability Study</themekey><themekey>USGS</themekey><themekey>United States Geological Survey</themekey><themekey>thickness</themekey><themekey>altitude</themekey><themekey>extent</themekey><themekey>regions</themekey><themekey>upper confining unit</themekey><themekey>FAS</themekey><themekey>base</themekey><themekey>geologic units</themekey><themekey>geology</themekey><themekey>extent</themekey><themekey>inlandWaters</themekey></theme>
```

The rest of the file is written nicely, but this particular element is causing (purely aesthetic) trouble. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

---

Below is a snippet of markup from the template xml file (save this as "template.xml" to run with code snippet at bottom). The flattening of tags only occurs when I parse an existing file and insert a new element, not when the xml is created from scratch using `lxml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fgdc_classic.xsl"?>
<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://water.usgs.gov/GIS/metadata/usgswrd/fgdc-std-001-1998.xsd">
    <keywords>
       <theme>
            <themekt>ISO 19115 Topic Categories</themekt>
            <themekey>environment</themekey>
            <themekey>geoscientificInformation</themekey>
            <themekey>inlandWaters</themekey>
        </theme>
        <place>
            <placekt>None</placekt>
            <placekey>Florida</placekey>
            <placekey>Georgia</placekey>
            <placekey>Alabama</placekey>
            <placekey>South Carolina</placekey>
        </place>
    </keywords>

</metadata>
```

Below is a snippet of code to be used with the snippet of markup (above):

```
# Create new theme element to insert into root
themekeys = ['Hydrogeology', 'Stratigraphy', 'inlandWaters']

tree = etree.parse(r'template.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

stream = []
for element in root.iter():
    if isinstance(element.tag, basestring):
        stream.append(element.tag)

        # Edit theme keywords
        if element.tag == 'keywords':
            theme = etree.Element('theme')
            themekt = etree.SubElement(theme, 'themekt').text = 'None'
            for tk in themekeys:
                themekey = etree.SubElement(theme, 'themekey').text = tk
            element.insert(0, theme)

# Write XML to new file
out_xml_file = 'test.xml'
etree.ElementTree(root).write(out_xml_file, method='xml', pretty_print=True)
with open(out_xml_file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(out_xml_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Can you perhaps provide a short code snippet that demonstrates the problem that I can just cut and paste? I cannot run the code in the question as-is (for one thing, I don't have your XML template).

Comment: @mzjn I just added a snippet of the markup from the template file. The flattening of tags only occurs when I parse an existing file and insert a new element, not when the xml is created from scratch using `lxml`. It probably has to do with whitespace -- I've tried using a parser that ignores whitespace and many of the previously nested elements become flattened once written to file, sometimes many of them run together on a single line.

Comment: "Flattening" is a structural operation -- referring to taking leaves out of subtrees and moving them up to top-level. I've adjusted the title to refer specifically to whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace this line:

```
tree = etree.parse(r'template.xml')
```

with these lines:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(r'template.xml', parser)
```

then it will work as expected. The trick is to use an [XMLParser](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) that has the `remove_blank_text` option set to `True`. Any existing ignorable whitespace will be removed and will therefore not disrupt the subsequent pretty-printing.

Comment: This is true, however I used that same code on the original template file which has many more lines and I end up with many elements becoming "flattened", sometimes many of them together on one line.

Comment: Strange. I cannot explain it. Perhaps you can provide a larger XML sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct. The problem seems to be stemming from a line of code where I am trying to replace an element wholesale. I must be doing it in such a way that whitespace is being created in an unintended manner since the written output looks good when I omit this piece of code. Thanks for your help...