# How to avoid incorrect indentation in generated XML file when inserting ElementTree in some Element?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, indentation

I'm dynamically generating a lot of XML data. Each document is intended as a test for specific feature(s) in a software that processes it.

A document consists of multiple different blocks. In order to keep things simple let's say the document above is what I work with:

```
<doc>
  <attributes>
    <attr/>
    <attr/>
  </attributes>
  <items>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </items>
</doc>
```

The number of `attr` elements varies and the same applies to the number of `item` ones. However the structure of each doesn't change (only the data inside).

In order to keep my Python script more readable I have stored a bunch of template XML files each of which represents a repeating element (with all of its children if any). In my main script using `lxml` I create `doc`, `attributes` and `items`. Given parameters for defining how many `item` and `attr` elements there need to be in the resulting XML document I simply do a loop, load the respective template, adjust the data inside and then append it to the respective parent (here `attributes` and `items` elements):

```
from lxml import etree

attrs = 2
its = 10

root = etree.Element('doc')
root.addprevious(etree.Comment('...'))
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

attributes = etree.SubElement(root, 'Attributes')
for a in range(0, attrs):
  attr = etree.parse('attribute.xml', parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True))
  attributes.append(attr.getroot()

items = etree.SubElement(root, 'Items')
for i in range(0, its):
  item = etree.parse('item.xml', parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True))
  items.append(item.getroot()

etree.tostring(doc, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

I've noticed one thing though, which isn't an error per se but is rather visible when looking at the generated XML document - the indentation is messed up exactly where the *sub-tree* XML has been inserted. I can fix this by using some XML formatting tool (for example Visual Studio Code's or Notepad++'s) but I'm wondering as to why this is happening.

Comment: Try using `remove_blank_text=True` when creating the XMLParser. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278249/407651.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you mind putting this in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`remove_blank_text=True`](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output) when creating the XML parser:

```
parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, remove_comments=True)
```

This will remove all ignorable whitespace and let the subsequent pretty-printing "start from scratch".