# Reformatting XML to standardize tabs/indents

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml file that needs to be pretty printed for human consumption.  For many years, we made changes with xmlspy and used it's gridview function to standaize the indents before checking in to git. I dont want to lock users in to that program so was planning on adding an python script to run on checkin that will read in the xml file, reformat it with somewhat standard indents and then write that out to a file which will get checked in.  I used the code below which is refernece below in many answers to similar questions.   It may work fine if your xml file has no `tabs` and `carriage-returns` however it seems to not touch formatting that are already there.   For example if my xml file looks like below I want the `<Grape>` to get put in line but that doesn't actually happen in my output.. the`<Grape>` has extra indents in the output file

**Example**

```
<Fruit>
  <Apple/>
     <Grape/>
  <Pear/>
</Fruit>
```

**Code**

```
import lxml.etree as etree
output_file = open("output.txt", "w")
parsed_file = etree.parse("input.xml")
parsed_bytes = (etree.tostring(parsed_file, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode"))
output_file.write(parsed_bytes)
```

**Additional Info From working through it more**
I think part of the problem is `pretty_print` does not seem to get called if I have any tabs/spaces in mt xml.  If my source file is pre-stripped the pretty print works fine but if I break this up in to two lines it doesnt print nice.

```
 <Fruit><Apple/><Grape/><Pear/></Fruit>
```

Comment: `etree.tostring()` accepts a `strip_text` keyword argument, try passing it `strip_text=True`.

Comment: You cant seem to run strip_text and pretty_print at same time.  if you run both the strip_text overpowers the pretty_print

Comment: Using a parser with `remove_blank_text` set to `True` might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278249/407651.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the parser setting of `remove_blank_text` that was needed

```
import lxml.etree as etree
output_file = open("output.xml", "w")

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True) 
parsed_file = etree.parse("inputstrong text.xml", parser)
parsed_bytes = (etree.tostring(parsed_file, pretty_print=True))
parsed_string = str(parsed_bytes, 'utf-8')
output_file.write(parsed_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<2>` is not in line, because you didn't provide *well-formed* XML code. To make your "XML" code *well-formed*, you should transform it to something like this:

```
<Numbers>
  <1 />
  <2 />
  <3 />
</Numbers>
```

or

```
<Numbers>
  <1>
     <2 />
  </1>
  <3 />
</Numbers>
```

**Finally:**
According to the [XML specification v1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n/) an [NTName](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) cannot start with a number. It must start with a [NameStartChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) (But I guess that your naming scheme was only for illustrative purposes).

Taking all of this into account, the result should be as expected.

Comment: The numbers were for illistrative purpoes.  I was just trying to illisutrate the tabs but yes I should have closed off the numbers.  My actual xml is fine but I have the same reults from the python code.   Will fix my example

Comment: I'm glad that we're on the same terms. Because this answer did attract some revenge votes (for me). But don't care about that!

Comment: I adjsuted my question to address the fact that my exampe was pourly formatted with numbers.  Thanks for pointing that out.