# Why my xml outpout file isn't formatting?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I use this code but it's not formatting my file:

```
formatTree = etree.parse(self.file)
formatTree.write(self.file, pretty_print=True)
```

and the result:

```
<ignoredIp>
    <ip>10.11.100.65</ip><ip>10.11.100.66</ip><ip>10.11.100.67</ip><ip>10.11.100.68</ip><ip>10.11.100.69</ip><ip>10.11.100.70</ip></ignoredIp>
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278249/407651

Comment: Thank you, it's okay. @mzjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write  this:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
formatTree = etree.parse(self.file, parser)
formatTree.write(self.file, pretty_print=True)
```

Thank you. @mzjn